# How do I upgrade Phonegap in my Phonegap app?

Tags: cordova

I have a Phonegap app that I started with an earlier version of Phonegap, that I want to upgrade to the latest version. What steps do I take to upgrade it?

I'm shooting for a general answer, but my specific case is Phonegap 1.1.0 -> 1.2.0

Comment: I should have mentioned that my specific case is on iOS

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I found this tonight and it seems more straightforward. See http://phonegap.com/blog/2013/11/28/phonegap-320-released/

### How to Upgrade PhoneGap

Mac and Linux:

```
$ sudo npm install -g phonegap
```

Windows:

```
C:\> npm install -g phonegap
```

### How to Upgrade an App

```
$ cd path/to/my-app
$ phonegap platform update android
```

You can substitute *android* for any platform name.

Comment: Well this is certainly /long/ overdue.

Answer (score 5):

Depends on the platform. For Android you just need to replace your .jar/.js files with the 1.2 versions and update the script tag to refer to the phonegap-1.2.0.js file.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. I couldn't find anything about updating android.

Answer (score 4):

Quoting Devgeeks Phonegap wiki link above, it looks like the iOS general case answer is create a new project and copy your content over to it.

> 1. Create a new project
> 2. Copy your files into the www folder EXCEPT the phonegap.*.js files
> 3. In your index.html, edit the script tag to point to the new phonegap.*.js file
> 4. If you have plugins, copy them to the Plugins folder then re-add them in Xcode (NOT as folder references in blue, they should be folder
>      groups in yellow).
> 5. Modify PhoneGap.plist to add your plugin mappings. More info here
> 6. Modify PhoneGap.plist to add your iframe external urls. More info here in the README FAQ

Comment: That is a good answer in all cases, including any future versions which may change in unknown ways. Get to know everything that is in the project and where it lives and what parts you need to change. If stuff ever moves around, you will be able to easily handle it.

Answer (score 2):

In iOS it can be that easy, but is sometimes problematic.

Although 1.1.0 -> 1.2.0 *should* be fine... just upgrade PhoneGap via the dmg/pkg and update the `phonegap-1.1.0.js` file in your project to `phonegap-1.2.0.js` from your `/Users/Shared/PhoneGap/Frameworks/PhoneGap.framework/www` folder.

If it doesn't work as expected, try the slightly more complicated version below:

http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/42243680/Upgrading%20your%20iOS%20PhoneGap%20Project

Comment: But that wouldn't update the Resources directory, or does that step get skipped for the special case of 1.1.0 -> 1.2.0?

Comment: Like I said, it is most likely fine in the specific case of 1.1.0 -> 1.2.0. - the last changes in the Resources dir for instance were in July, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Later versions of Phonegap have added guides for this:</strike>

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/guide_upgrading_ios_index.md.html

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/guide_upgrading_android_index.md.html

I thought I saw a script around in the SDK to do this as well, but I cannot find it now.

Update: Just follow Zkent's answer. Or don't use PhoneGap.

Comment: Changing this to the accepted answer is very important. There has been considerable change since the original answer.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was thinking. Hate to accept my own answer, but time has passed, things have changed, and following the upgrade guides is probably the best plan nowadays.