# How to upgrade from phonegap 2.9 to phonegap 3.5 (project directory could not be found error)

Tags: android, cordova, cmd

I have an android application that i built on PhoneGap 2.7.I installed phonegap 3.5 using cmd and tried to upgrade an app as shown here

[How do I upgrade Phonegap in my Phonegap app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8157862/how-do-i-upgrade-phonegap-in-my-phonegap-app)

But when i do it using cmd it gives me the following error:[image]

Unlike phonegap 3.5 the android application that I built in PhoneGap 2.7 does not have a platform folder.So what am I supposed to?and how can I verify if it is upgraded or not?

I had also seen these phonegap documentation

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/guide_platforms_android_upgrade.md.html#Upgrading%20Android

But It does not show how to directly upgrade from 2.7 to 3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think phonegap platform update works for upgrading from something older than 3.x.

For phonegap/cordova cli to work it has to detect a project with the structure of 3.x projects.

To upgrade your project in 2.x you have to

> - install phonegap or cordova cli (which you seem to already have done, but if you don't plan on using phonegap build, I suggest you use
>     cordova instead of phonegap. if not please replace cordova by phonegap
>     in next steps)
> - open a cmd and cd to a folder in wich you will want to put your project
> - create the new project from the www folder you had in your old project:
>
>   cordova create nameforprojectfolder com.test.app Testapp --copy-from=pathtooldwwwfolder
> - change current dir to the newly created folder
> - add the android platform:
>
>   cordova platform add android
> - in cordova/phonegap 3.x no plugin is added by default so you will have to add all the plugins you use :
>
>   cordova plugin add uri.of.plugin
> - customize config.xml to your needs
> - build the android project (this will create files in the platforms/android folder)
>
>   cordova build android
> - You may need to customize AndroidManifest.xml in platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml

Now you can use the CLI to work with your project.

Comment: What If i create a new android project using phonegap 3.5 and import it in eclipse and then just replace the www folder with the one I want.Will that work?

Comment: The steps I explained are to create a new project from your previous project (option  --copy-from allows to import your old www). You must add all the plugins you need and run either build or prepare before you import the project in eclipse. When you import in eclipse you have to remember to import the 2 projects. But since I use the CLI I see no more interest in using Eclipse.

Comment: If you use eclipse with a phonegap 3 project you have to remember that if you need to add a new plugin with the cli you will see it in eclipse only after building the project and this will erase the www folder you see in eclipse and overwrite with the root www folder of the project. (remember to save it before) Or you can use plugman to manage plugins directly in the platform/android project. See Lorenzo's answer there : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25024009/adding-cordova-phonegap-plugins-manually-to-existing-android-projects/25031213?noredirect=1#comment38947613_25031213

Comment: Well everything went fine but when try to run the project in emulator there is no action.It shows refreshing external folders and then does nothing.However 'phonegap run android' works properly.

Comment: Ok, I had a problem in android manifest file.It gave me error that manifest is out of sync.So I did clean project and now everything works fine.Thanks