# Upgrading cordova of existing project

Tags: node.js, cordova, sencha-touch

I already have a Cordova project built on older versions(2.3.0). Now I want to upgrade it to Cordova 3.3.1. I installed Cordova 3.3.1-0.1.2 using npm

```
npm install -g cordova@3.3.1-0.1.2
```

Then I am trying to upgrade my project with command

> update_cordova_subproject

I don't see that command file available in the bin folder of Cordova installed location. In my case it is C:\Users\KAVVA01\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\bin.

I can see only cordova.cmd in that. Where can I find "update_cordova_subproject" command file.

Any thoughts?

Comment: check my answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25032226/how-to-upgrade-from-phonegap-2-9-to-phonegap-3-5-project-directory-could-not-be/25035441?noredirect=1#comment38968802_25035441 and next time please try to search before you ask new question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update_cordova_subproject will not be available if your Cordova version is older than 3.0. 
There is no direct way to upgrade older versions < 3.0.